# Custom css to format tr td but not if bold detected inside td

Tags: html, css

I dont know if this is possible but...I am trying to format a table with css, to have a specific look. This is for a wordpress site that will be updated by my client. The problem is that she is going to be copying/pasting tables with a specific format, and i want the table to have that format without her doing any extra work.
This is what i have so far.

[image]

I want the cells with the **Bold** text to not have a dotted line bellow them.
Right now i am formating the tr lines to add the dotted lines like this:

**html**

```
<table class="dotted" border="0" width="450" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><strong>Argento</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cake Box Lady</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">Postcard from Morocco</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><strong>Bellini</strong></td>
</tr>
.....
```

**css**

```
.dotted tr:nth-child(even) {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px white dotted;
}
.dotted tr:nth-child(odd) {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px white dotted;
}
```

Is there a way i can do this without having to add a custom class tag for each  that has the bold text in it ?

This is how i want it to look like, but this is all done manually...That's what i am trying to avoid.
[image]

ps: Sometimes the tables might have more than 1 'data' under the bold letters so its not always odd, even lines, when it comes to the 'title' and the 'plays' bellow them. (this is a site for musical plays)

-Thanks

Comment: Just use one odd only and remove even (seeing your current design)

Comment: Yeah, i just noticed that i copy pasted an example that by chance has only 1 theatrical play under the title...its not always the case...sometimes it could be 4 plays under Bellini (for example)

Comment: Are the bold text inside `colspan=2`?

Comment: You need to add a class on them. There's no other way around in css.

Comment: Thats what i thought :/
Thanks

Comment: @Manoj Kumar
Yeah the bold are always under colspan 2

Comment: @Manoj got any idea :) ?

Comment: Are you in for a jQuery solution?

Comment: @LinkinTED Sure if it helps :) ? I can import a js script. The template already uses jquery.

Comment: I see you already found your solution, but in case you are curious, this would be the jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/h561f8rw/

Comment: @LinkinTED I'll probably need to do stuff like that again with this site...ofc this js will be highly appreciated :) 
Thanks man for the effort and time spent to write it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @Manoj Kumar Yeah the bold items are always under colspan 2

Since you stated the above comment, I have a CSS hack for it.

1. Change your CSS to have dotted border only on `td` instead of `tr` elements.
2. Target the elements with `colspan=2` with attribute selector to have no border.

```css
table {
  background: gray;
}
.dotted td:nth-child(even) {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px white dotted;
}
.dotted td:nth-child(odd) {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px white dotted;
}
.dotted td[colspan="2"] { /* Attribute selector */
  border: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<table class="dotted" border="0" width="450" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Argento</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cake Box Lady</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">Postcard from Morocco</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Bellini</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Argento</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cake Box Lady</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">Postcard from Morocco</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Bellini</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Argento</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cake Box Lady</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">Postcard from Morocco</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Bellini</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Argento</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cake Box Lady</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">Postcard from Morocco</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cake Box Lady</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">Postcard from Morocco</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cake Box Lady</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">Postcard from Morocco</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Bellini</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you so much :)